# How do you nullify an attribute in Core Data?

Tags: ios, core-data

Say I have a Core Data NSManagedObject that has an attribute which stores a image. If I want to delete the image but not the NSMAnagedObject how do I do it?

Right now I'm using. This seems to be working but I am getting intermittent crashes related to this code so I'd like to be sure.

```
-(void)deletePhoto{
note.thumbnail = nil; //This is a thumbnail image
[context deleteObject:note.image]; //This is an image related to the object via a to-one relationship

NSError *error;
if (![context save:&error])
    NSLog(@"Error saving: %@", [error localizedDescription]);
```

}
[image]

Comment: What errors do you get and at exactly which line?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you should let Core Data handle that. You should set the relationship to "Cascade Delete" and then set it to nil in code.

```
note.image = nil; // Rather than delete object.
```

Comment: And if I want to set an attribute to nothing?

Comment: If you delete an object in a relationship directly, depending on how you have your delete rules set up, the object on the other end of the relationship may or may not understand that the other object has disappeared. I suspect your object graph is getting out of balance because of the direct object deletions.